# Prevent access to a smartcapture survey in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage, smart-capture, survey

I would like to know if it is possible to prevent that a single person complete twice or more times a survey built using Smart Capture in a Cloud Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Data Extension where you store the results, make sure you also save the `SubscriberKey` and `Completed` (TRUE/FALSE) values.

On the SmartCapture form you store the `SubscriberKey` as unique variable and the Completed value as `TRUE`. Essentially saving information who actually completed your Survey.

On the Cloud Page where you have the SmartCapture form, add a small AMPScript snippet to check your Data Extension for the Completed value via `LookUp`, if it's `True` - then redirect Contact to somewhere else instead.

```
%%[ 
VAR @Key, @Email, @Status
SET @Key = RequestParameter("Key")
SET @Email = RequestParameter("Email")
SET @Status = Lookup('FormAnswers', "Completed", "Key", @Key)
IF @Status == "True" THEN
%%=Redirect('http://google.com')=%%
ENDIF
]%%
```

For an example I would advise to set up a new Cloud Page for this matter, something that says:

> Thank You, you have already submitted your response.

Or you can also send to your company home-page or anywhere else for that matter.

You can also display the previously submitted answers in the form and lock the page with SSJS if you don't like the idea of redirecting though.

To redirect user to a Cloud Page with some attributes 'attached' with the link, use [**CloudPagesURL()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) in your Email. Here's an example where you need to replace `XXX` with your Cloud Page ID:

```
%%[
VAR @Email, @Key
SET @Key = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @Email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
]%%

%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(XXX,'Email',@Email,'Key',@Key))=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to do this is to pass a primary key from email to survey page, then do a lookup to the receiving DE and see if it has already been submitted. For example you can do a 'SurveyID' which could be filled by random chars via `GUID()`.

For Example: `https://www.yoursurvey.com?sid=8934893-343234-343`

Which would be created via: `CONCAT('https://www.yoursurvey.com?sid=', @SurveyID)` with `@SurveyID` being filled by: `SET @SurveyID = GUID()` and then inserted into a 'SurveyResultsDE'

Then you would need a field inside of the DE called 'Submitted' - I usually have this be a date and have it fill in with `NOW()` inside the form.

For example: `<input type="hidden" name="Submitted" value="%%=NOW()=%%" />`

You then do a lookup on your survey page to see if 'Submitted' has a value already or not.

`SET @alreadysubmitted = Lookup('yourSurveyDE', "Submitted", "SurveyID", @SurveyID)`

Then you will do a conditional to see if Submitted contains a value or not.

`IF NOT EMPTY(@alreadysubmitted) THEN {{already submitted content}} ELSE {{survey form content }} ENDIF`

This will let you determine if they have already submitted or not and display content accordingly.

I usually also include something for if there is no pkey in the URL passed. But that is up to you.

Also make sure to make the pkey non editable in times where it is passed.

Comment: Why did someone downvote my answer? Next time please leave a comment on what you felt needed improvement and I will adjust accordingly.